# Chrome shows 'data;.' in address bar while using selenium to login

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm using selenium to test login page like this:

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time

browser = webdriver.Chrome()


def execute():
    browser.get("https://test.com")
    browser.find_element_by_id("user_name").send_keys("user_name")
    browser.find_element_by_id("password").send_keys("password")
    time.sleep(1)
    browser.find_element_by_id("submit_button").click()
```

with Google Chrome version 79.0.3945.117, chromedriver version 79.0.3945.36, selenium version 3.141.0 and MacOS High Sierra version 10.13.6.

But when I run the program, chrome open a blank page with `data:,` in address bar.

What went wrong? 
Thankyou!

Comment: Are you calling execute() method ?

Comment: I'm called execute() method in main.py file

Comment: It is working fine on Ubuntu. If you could add other code too, this will help people reproduce the error.